# Linux: Kill process based on arguments

Tags: linux, kill

How can I kill a process based on its command line arguments? 
`killall`, `pgrep`, and `pkill` seem to only work based on the process name.

I need this to be able to differentiate between a number of applications running inside Java virtual machines, where `java` is the process name for all of them and the actual application name can be found by looking at the command line arguments.

This can be done manually with `ps aux | grep myapp.jar` and then manually killing the pid from the output, but I'd like a command to do something equivalent automatically.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

`pgrep`/`pkill` take a `-f` flag. From the `man` page:

```
-f    The pattern is normally only matched against the process name.
      When -f is set, the full command line is used.
```

For example:

```
$ sleep 30& sleep 60&
[1] 8007
[2] 8008

$ pkill -f 'sleep 30'
[1]  - terminated  sleep 30

$ pgrep sleep
8008
```

Comment: +1, but my *bash 4.1.5* doesn't work for a colon after an ampersand (as in the example's first line)... `bash: syntax error near unexpected token ';'` ... It does work in a *case* statement when the ampersand is followed by `;;` ... maybe you are using a different shell(?)

Comment: @jw013 I was actually using `zsh`, which supports the syntax I used. Leaving it out works in both though, so I removed it

Comment: @MichaelMrozek ok nvm then :)  I wonder if unix.SE has a higher proportion of `zsh` users than elsewhere - I only seem to find `zsh` users here.

Comment: pgrep and pkill take a regular expression. So `pkill -f 'sleep .0'` would kill `sleep 30` and `sleep 60` but not `sleep 35`. If you want to match any parameter do `pkill -f 'sleep .* myArg'`.

Comment: `pkill -f ".*java .* org.apache.rocketmq.console.App"` This help to kill a java process with given args.

Answer (score 5):

Replace `argument` below with a regular expression that must much the full command line of a process:

```
kill `ps -eo pid,args --cols=10000 | awk '/argument/ && $1 != PROCINFO["pid"] { print $1 }'`
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `htop` to view all currently running processes with their command line arguments and to kill a selected process.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have pkill or whatever, just use proc/[1-9]*/cmdline

```
grep -a myapp.jar /proc/[1-9]*/cmdline|tr '\0' ' '|grep -v grep|awk -F/ '{print $3}'
```