# Kill only one Java process

Tags: process, java, kill

I usually run few Java applications, one for server running locally and other for some IDE like NetBeans. And from time to time, after lots of redeployments, my server get stuck on OutOfMemoryException so I need to kill Java process in order to reboot.

So I do `pkill -9 java` but this also kills my running IDE which I don't want to. So how do I kill only application linked to running server and not the other ones?I assume that they all are running under same process but there has to be some way how to distuingish them.

Comment: look at your process table (via `top` or `ps`) and choose the right one and kill it by PID (kill -9 PID_number).

Comment: Oh yes, I can see that now. So I just need to kill process with right `PID`. Thanks a lot

Comment: I need to automate this. How to get the PID for the particular program?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For killing a process that is associated with multiple processes, you need to kill that by using process id associated with that process.

To get the process id of that java process run

```
ps -A |grep java
```

output of this command will give the list of java processes running on your system. Note down Process ID (PID) of that process whom you want to kill and run

```
kill -9 PID
```

Comment: If you want to kill ALL java processes by one command `ps ax | grep java | grep -v 'grep' | cut -d '?' -f1 | xargs kill -9`

Answer (score 18):

IMO the best solution is:

```
pkill -9 -f <nameOfYourJavaAplication>
```

Comment: Perfect. I used  `ps -fC java` to find `nameOfYourJavaAplication` (in `-Dprogram.name`)

Answer (score 11):

Instead of using `ps` and `grep`, you can use `ps`'s `-C` flag to select all commands listed with the name 'java'. You may also want to use `ps`'s `-f` flag to print the full command name of each listed process. That way, you can see what each java process is actually doing. Here is the command in full: `ps -fC java`.

You could also use `pgrep` to list all java processes. `pgrep -a java` will return the PID and full command line of each java process.

Once you have the PID of the command you wish to kill, use `kill` with the `-9` (SIGKILL) flag and the PID of the java process you wish to kill. Java doesn't always stop when it receives a 'SIGTERM' signal (processes are allowed to handle 'SIGTERM'), so sending it the 'SIGKILL' signal, which makes init kill the program without warning it first, is often necessary.

For example, if `ps -fC java` returns

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
jeff      9014  8890  0 08:51 pts/0    00:00:00 java IDE
jeff     11775  8890  6 08:59 pts/0    00:00:00 java TestProgram
```

or `psgrep -a java` returns

```
9014 java IDE
11775 java TestProgram
```

and you wish to kill `java TestProgram`, you should run `kill -9 11775`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a script to find and kill your (specific) running program using a pattern from the command line of the program (and not just every java thing you got running), then:

```
pgrep -f pattern # shows the PID
pkill -f pattern
```

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/31111/249209

Comment: Notice that "pkill" [was already mentioned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/64677/117549) in Marek R's answer of Feb 13 '13

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use

```
jps -l
```

command to get all of the process id's of java processes and then issue

```
kill PROCESS_ID
```

command

Answer (score 0):

`jps` and `jcmd` are tools specialized in displaying only Java processes information and PIDs.

You can explore their options for a more detailed output.

Comment: Those only list themselves on my computer.

Comment: Then, are you sure there are other Java processes running ?!

Comment: Yes. I had Cassandra or Elassadra running when testing your command.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script one can use to automate the process.

Replace the `<PROCESS_NAME>` part with whatever java is executing.

```
#!/bin/sh
process=`ps -ef | grep -v awk | awk -e '/java.*<PROCESS_NAME>/ { print $2 }'`
kill ${process}
```

Note: I did not put the `-9`. I should not be required unless you capture signals and `SIGTERM` (the default) fails. I would also suggest you use the signal name which makes it easier to read:

```
kill -TERM ${process}
```

**WARNING**

Before executing the `kill ...` make sure that the `$process` variable gets set as expected. The `ps -ef` may different between Unices so `awk` may need to print a different parameter.

**Note**

The `<PROCESS_NAME>` could be changed into a variable. Just remember that if you have to type it on your command line each time, you are likely to make mistakes once in a while. I find it easier to have multiple copy of the script with the correct name.

Also important: notice the single quotes for the `awk` script. That means you need to close and reopen the string with the variable in between. Something like this *should* work (untested):

```
process=`ps -ef | grep -v awk | awk -e '/java.*'"${PROCESS_NAME}"'/ { print $2 }'`
```

Answer (score 0):

My gradle projects don't call /bin/java directly.  They create a symlink based on project name at runtime.  In this example ps shows "java_my_app" instead of just "java".  You can easily pkill or killall the correct JVM.  This also helps identify processes in top, htop etc.

In all my Java projects' build.gradle files I add:

```
apply from: '../shared.gradle'
```

~/.gradle/gradle.properties:

```
org.gradle.java.home=/opt/jdk
```

settings.gradle:

```
rootProject.name = 'my_app'
```

shared.gradle:

```
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Path

tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
    def javaExecutablesPath = project.property('org.gradle.java.home') + '/bin'
    println "javaExecutablesPath=" + javaExecutablesPath
    Path j1 = Path.of(javaExecutablesPath).resolve("java")
    Path jLink = Path.of(javaExecutablesPath).resolve("java_" + rootProject.name)
    if (!Files.exists(j1)){
        println j1 + " is missing."
    } else if (Files.exists(jLink)) {
        println jLink + " exists, OK."
    } else {
        java.nio.file.Path p = Files.createSymbolicLink(jLink, j1)
        println "created " + p
    }
    executable = jLink.toFile()
}
```